# Augmented dicky fuller (ADF) vs Breusch–Godfrey test on R-Studio

Tags: r, statistics

I have time series data (one Y variable and one X variable). I ran the ADF test on the residuals of the regression (with lags up to 4). The tests point to unit roots being present in the residuals beyond lags of 3 but not for lags of 1 and 2.

Separately, I ran the Breusch–Godfrey test on the regression to check for serial correlation and the results indicated the presence of serial correlation up to order 1.

My questions are:

1. Intuitively, are the 2 tests testing for the same problem? What is the main difference between serial correlation and the existence of unit roots in the residuals of the regression?
2. What do you do if both tests point to different conclusions?
3. Does using the `gls(Y~X,corr=corARMA(p=1,q=0))` method treat both the problems of serial correlation and unit roots?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ADF test is a test on unit roots, and BG test is a test on the serial correlation in residuals. These tests serve different purposes, i.e. autocorrelation in residuals does not mean uni root and vice versa.